# How can i get Json records from all the pages with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created an API endpoint with Django Rest Framework. I'm now querying this endpoint from a Jquery script. The problem is that, once the request is sent, DRF will return Json data only from the first page of my API endpoint. How can i set it to retrieve all the data, instead?

Here is my view:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
```

My serializer:

```
class tstSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = tst
        fields = ('Amount', 'Perc')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return tst.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

I'm querying the endpoint to this url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tst`

Comment: unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right - you have default pagination enabled, so you receive data page-by-page. You can disable pagination for your view:

```
class tstList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = tst.objects.all()
    serializer_class = tstSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    pagination_class = None
```

Answer (score 1):

Read [DRF pagination docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setting-the-pagination-style), so you understand the default settings it adds to your projcet's `settings.py`.

If pagaingtion still useful for you but you just want to disable it for some views

try to create something like this

```
class UnlimitedPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 0
```

also I recommend creating a `paganation.py` file  in your project and put the above class in it

Then `import UnlimitedPagination` class from `paganation.py` and use it in your view

```
pagination_class = UnlimitedPagination
```